# How to create a new GameObject, without adding it to the scene?

Tags: unity, resource-management

I'm creating what is essentially my own prefab system. Game objects are defined by a human readable data file. I'd like to create an empty GameObject, load it with the components defined in the data file and have it ready and waiting for an `Instantiate()` call. However, whenever I use `GameObject go = new GameObject()` a new game object is added to the scene.

Using Unity built in prefabs, I can load a prefab as a GameObject, and it's not added to the scene. (See example below)

The rationale behind this is I'd like to have one list that contains GameObjects, some generated by loading Unity prefabs and others created by my custom prefab system. This needs to happen at run time, and can't involve the Unity Editor (since ideally end users would be able to define their own data files).

How can I create a new GameObject, without Unity automatically instantiating it for me?

---

For example, I can make a call like this:

```
Resources.LoadAll("PrefabsDirectory", typeof(GameObject))
```

And I'll get a list of GameObjects, none of which are added to the scene when the call is made. Essentially, I'm creating a `LoadAll` method for my own prefabs, and likewise, I don't want to instantiate the GameObjects when the call is made.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't. I think you'll have to delay the instantiation of your class.

Comment: It's been a while since I touched Unity, but if it turns out there isn't a way around this, could you just *remove* the object from the scene immediately after and have the desired outcome, just slightly inefficiently?

Comment: @KevinReid I believe the only way to do that is call `Destroy` on the GameObject. Which removes it from the scene and releases it, making it unusable.

Comment: How about creating it and then deactivating it?

Comment: @PandaPajama has a good idea. Calling `go.SetActive(false)` is the best way to create something like an object pool. It's not exactly what you want, but perhaps you could have a small group of inactive objects that are later cloned for your custom instantiation.

Comment: or place them outside visible areas, still not perfect

Comment: Yeah, feels pretty hacky, might be no way to get around that. I tried putting them as children to a common empty parent, and setting them all to inactive as I loaded them before asking the question. It just felt messy, not something I'd want to release to other developers. Placing them outside visible areas is worse, since their Update methods would still be called.

Comment: @Byte56: Why exactly do you want to pre-instantiate your custom prefabs and not just compose the GO with required components on the fly while instantiating them using a factory like pattern? For what I understood you want to allow users to "serialize" prefabs using "their own data files", so you have to read those files at run time anyway and instantiate the required components.. am I missing something?

Comment: @Heisenbug As mentioned in the post, it's so that Unity prefabs and custom prefabs can live together. It's not *required* to move forward, it's just nice to have. What I currently have in place is what you're suggesting. Custom components are created on the fly when requested. I'd rather have just one object in my factory than two. In many cases it doubles the code and it requires a number of workarounds to provide the same functionality from each. (For example, if I wanted to get the mesh from a prefab, without instantiating, I could do that, if it's still in data file form, that's harder).

Comment: Since asking I've tried creating an empty prefab, loading that for each data file and modifying it. However, in editor mode, that modifies the saved prefab. I can get around this by instantiating and disconnecting the prefab (but that's really no different than just creating a new game object). In build mode, this appears to work for one object, but not others, I have to dig deeper into that and find out why, I imagine it's because it's not possible to load multiple copies of the same prefab.

Comment: Are you doing this in Editor or at runtime? I think there is a way to create a game object that's not added in the scene, but can only be executed in editor scripts.

Comment: @pek "This needs to happen at run time, and can't involve the Unity Editor"

Comment: Sorry, didn't catch that. Curious to see the solution to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could change the [GameObject's hideFlags?](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/HideFlags.html)

I just tried running this:

```
GameObject myGameObject = new GameObject ();
myGameObject.name = "Obvious Name";

myGameObject.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideInHierarchy;
```

...and it's there, but it's not in the hierarchy. Technically, it's in the scene, but you don't see it until you change it's flags back to HideFlags.None. It's not the answer you're looking for, but at least as far as releasing this to developers goes, it's cleaner than grouping your objects.

Comment: This, paired with disabling it (so none of the scripts execute), could work. I'll give it a try and let you know. It's still a work around, but I think that's what I'm left with at this point. And, for all we know, this could be what's done internally, though I doubt it.

Comment: @Byte56: I tought it was a workaround too, but I actually I discovered these days that Unity does the exactly same thing when previewing animations: it instantiate hidden gameobject in the scene and render them to the preview frame with a dedicated camera. So maybe it doesn't sound so clean, but actually this solution seems to be used also internally.

Comment: Sorry for the late accept. I just got around to implementing this and it works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do `go = new GameObject();` without adding it to the scene.

I'm working on an RTS where the player base needs to be persistent, and essentially, we serialize everything they've done and load it back in at run time using modified assets from the store.

Most output to XML or JSON so it's pretty straight forward to load the file and manipulate it as you wish.

Comment: Thanks Marc. Can you provide evidence or rationale for not being able to create a new GameObject without adding it to the scene? I have serialization code of my own, so that's not a problem, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that exact thing, unfortunately. However, you can accomplish the same design pattern (ie. abstract away the building of your objects, and then simply call them with a single command later) through a [Factory pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html).

When you want an object, call something like `Factory.CreateGameEntity()`, and that method will handle everything behind the scenes.

Comment: It's more complex than you might think though, making it not as clean. I'll post an answer will full details, but essentially the parser has to be pretty complex. For example, if I want to test if a prefab has a component, before instantiating, it's as simple as `GetComponent<>() != null`. With my data files, the parser has to search for the correct component in the data. Same for getting a value from inside a component, and so on. The `GameObject` class provides a lot of functionality that needs to be duplicated by the parser.

Comment: If you can provide evidence or even some rationale for why this can't be done, it would make this answer complete.

Comment: I'll see later if I can find any definitive documentation about this, for now all I can find are these forum threads http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/189628-Create-Prefab-at-Runtime-Possible - http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/366273/create-prefab-from-gameobjects-at-runtime.html - http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/19736/creating-new-prefab-at-runtime.html

Answer (score -1):

The right way is to make a prefab , you allocate that prefab as an Object , then whenever you want to instantiate just use the reference of this Object and cast it as a GameObject.

ex :

```
private Object prefab;


public static GameObject Create(void)
{
   return (Instantiate(prefab , position , rotation) as GameObject);
}
```

Comment: That's using the existing prefab system. As my question states, I'm essentially creating my own prefab system. Part of the requirements are "can't involve the Unity Editor". Creating a prefab uses the Unity Editor.

Comment: That you cant do , you would need a license for developper using their SDK to then be able to make your own data . Unless I am wrong , they wont share their code without any bling bling . But I know some people have been able to export scenes from Unity to their own game engine

Comment: Well, it's clearly possible since I did create my own prefab system using the selected answer. You can learn how to do it in the course I created, found in my profile.

Comment: no thanks I am a graduated game programmer :) Well if you succeed that great for you , dont need it to make games

Comment: It's a system that essentially allows end users to make prefabs. This is pretty useful in games for mods and other end-user created content. (So yeah, I think it's pretty useful in making games).

Comment: Maybe the way I wrote it let you think I was against it , I agree that this is useful after all , but my point is that you can already customize a prefab , that is its purpose , so I never had to make my own under Unity , but keep going that might be better than the default one .

Comment: The whole point of the system is for the end user to be able to use it, without having the game in the Unity Editor. It's not about being able to customize a prefab or being better than the default system. It's just so the user can create prefabs without the Unity editor. So, no, it's not true that you can "already customize a prefab" outside of the Unity editor. You can't do anything with prefabs outside the Unity editor except instantiate them.

Comment: Ok I get it now , I misunderstood the whole thing . I thought you want to create another prefab format that Unity could be able to read it ..Understood , good one :) my bad

Answer (score -1):

To load a prefab into a variable so you can instantiate it later you would use the following code:

```
 GameObject ball = (GameObject)(Resources.Load ("myPrefab"));
```

I've done this in a project with Unity 5.5.
It will be available to instantiate but not in the scene or part of the hierarchy until instantiated as normal.

Comment: I feel you've read the question wrong. This answer involves using the *default* prefab system. This question asks in context of creating a *custom* prefab system, where this is not accessible. The example at the bottom serves to further highlight this.

Comment: "How can I create a new GameObject, without Unity automatically instantiating it for me?"   Is the question that was asked and this code answered it. The code can be altered to obtain the results desired with custom loading systems.

Comment: This is essentially what I describe in the example included in the question. And it works fine for prefabs, but not for creating new game objects from data files.